# Jenkins pipeline: passing in data variable as string into curl command

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

So I'm trying to pass in a string (data) into this sendSlackMessage function but it's not going into the curl command correctly. data is being passed in from my jenkinsfile.

It's working fine in the echo command though.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
data = """{'channel': '#mychannel','username': 'jenkins-bot','icon_emoji': ':lol:','text': 'HERERERERE (<$BUILD_URL|Open>)','attachments': [['color': '#36a64f','fields': ['title': 'UPDATING INFOR','value': 'HELLOWORLD','short': 'true']]]}"""

void sendSlackMessage(String data) {
        this.steps.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo hello world ${data} hello world again")
        this.steps.sh(returnStdout: true, script: "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '${data}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T12345671/sdfsdfsdf/sdf7sdf7gsdf")
    }
```

Comment: you can try write the JSON payload into a file,  then use `--data @<file path>` in curl cmd.  And you can check the payload by `cat <file path>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below implementation

```
data = """{'channel': '#mychannel','username': 'jenkins-bot','icon_emoji': ':lol:','text': 'HERERERERE (<$BUILD_URL|Open>)','attachments': [['color': '#36a64f','fields': ['title': 'UPDATING INFOR','value': 'HELLOWORLD','short': 'true']]]}"""

void sendSlackMessage(String data) {
   List curlCommand = []
   curlCommand.add('curl -X POST -H')
   curlCommand.add('\'Content-type: application/json\'')
   curlCommand.add('--data')
   curlCommand.add(data) // Maybe you have to see if you see to add a single quote here and escape it
   curlCommand.add('https://hooks.slack.com/services/T12345671')
   sh (
      returnStdout: true, 
      script: curlCommand.join(" "),
      label: "send slack message"
   )
}
```